# MissingPluginException while using plugin for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I am trying to use the plugin

```
_launchURL(url) async {
  await launch("www.google.com");
}
```

I have put "www.google.com" just for debugging purposes.

The error I get is MissingPluginException :

```
E/flutter ( 8299): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)
E/flutter ( 8299): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:278:7)
E/flutter ( 8299): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8299): #1      launch (package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart:47:19)
E/flutter ( 8299): #2      _launchURL (file:///Users/matejsimunic/Work/dart/suhail/lib/main.dart:834:9)
E/flutter ( 8299): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8299): #3      _TripDetailBodyState.build.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/matejsimunic/Work/dart/suhail/lib/main.dart:818:19)
E/flutter ( 8299): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:494:14)
E/flutter ( 8299): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:549:30)
E/flutter ( 8299): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter ( 8299): #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
E/flutter ( 8299): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:94:7)
E/flutter ( 8299): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
E/flutter ( 8299): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
E/flutter ( 8299): #11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
E/flutter ( 8299): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
E/flutter ( 8299): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
E/flutter ( 8299): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 8299): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
E/flutter ( 8299): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
E/flutter ( 8299): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:13)
E/flutter ( 8299): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:5)
```

restarting the app from ide doesn't work.

Comment: I had that problem when using image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
with flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0 I had to remove Facebook support from my app

Answer (score 321, accepted):

If you are using hot restart or hot reload, it won't do the trick.
Since Flutter has to inject plugin dependencies into the platform-specific parts of your app, hot restart/hot reload is not enough to trigger the injection.
Check this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912) for more.

Close the app and execute `flutter run` command.

Comment: Its better to clean the run one before using the command 'flutter run'. To clean use the command 'flutter clean'

Comment: No need to do anything, just close the app and re-run/re-compile. It worked for me. Thanks to ask.

Comment: @Kamlesh That's exactly what is mentioned in the last line of the solution. The first paragraph is just to explain why the exception might be occurring.

Answer (score 50):

```
flutter clean
```

Inside the console did the job as stated [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912)

Comment: So simple -- and yet this has saved me hours of hair-pulling. Great tip.

Answer (score 23):

I faced this Error when using Url_launcher package. just had to stop and run the app, issue got solved

Comment: Yes, because the URL needs to be set up in native settings. so it will be done after rerunning the flutter project.

Answer (score 15):

Simply Run these commands..

either--

Flutter clean

or

Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 9):

just open terminal and

**Step1**
Delete all the temporary file generated during the build process this is by removing the `build/` directory by running this command
`flutter clean`

**Step 2**
After deleting your `build/` directory run this command to fetch and download dependencies indicated in your `pubspec.yaml` file
`flutter pub get`

**Step 3**
This command builds and runs your application to a connected device or environment of choice, is to validate if everything is working as expected.
`flutter run`

Its worked for me,
Thanks have a good day .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

Had problem while using flutter toast dependency and dependencies like facebook_login. I followed these steps and resolved it:

1. First, u need to test whether these toast and shared preference dependencies are causing problems or some other dependencies cause the problem.
2. For testing that, u need to create a new seprate flutter project having the same flutter toast and shared preference dependency and check now if u r able to get toasts or not.
3. If u r getting toast so there is no problem with ur toast dependency.
4. The problem might be in ur one of the social media dependency.

In my case, I followed the above steps and found that problem was in facebook dependency. Finally, I found that I did not provide details of my app at facebook developer console. So implemented that and my app was fine.

Comment: Thanks brother, you saved me, I was also struggling with same problem facebook dependency, I was amazed why the plugins are not working while they are working on the other app correctly, great!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was for the cached_network_image plugin , I have removed cached_network_image from pubspec.yaml and replaced the implementation with Image.network and the problem has disappeared

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had this problem with the image picker, then I followed the documentation and used an emulator with api 29+, it didn't work before because I was using an emulator with api 28  https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling and installing the app works for me

Answer (score 1):

i think if you have already done  **flutter pub get**  on the dependency, and added all the requirements for the given platform you just have to  **flutter run** your app