# MissingPluginException in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to use image picker but I am unable too fetch.
Whenever I called Imagepicker, it is showing error as **No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker**.
Please let me know of this issue.

I updated my question and added pubspec.yaml

```
    name: demo_flutter
description: A new Flutter application.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  video_player: ^0.5.2
  image_picker: ^0.5.0+1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/onnet.png



  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Can you post your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: please check my updated post

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get -v` ? I am here to qa the obvious.
Btw, here is the example for the image_picker
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: solution for this error is disused here [MissingPluginException while using plugin for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter)

Answer (score 5):

use command on terminal (cmd)

```
flutter clean
```

then rebuild your app
its work for me.

Comment: if it were that simple