# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listenForCode on channel sms_autofill)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a project and before merging the code with my teammates, package *sms_autofill* runs normally, but after the code got merged, I've already run *flutter clean* but it still shows two erros as below:

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listenForCode on channel sms_autofill)
```

and

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAppSignature on channel sms_autofill)
```

My code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/model/auth.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/util/exception/ResponseException.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/view/welcome/welcome.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/view/home/home.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/widget/loaders/color_loader_3.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/widget/loaders/color_loader_4.dart';
import 'package:rentto_tenant/widget/loading_widget.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';
import 'package:pin_code_text_field/pin_code_text_field.dart';

import '../../constant/color.dart';
import '../../constant/dimen.dart';

class SMSVerificationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uuid;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String password;
  final String requestType;

  const SMSVerificationPage(
      {Key key, this.uuid, this.phoneNumber, this.password, this.requestType})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SMSVerificationPageState createState() => _SMSVerificationPageState();
}

class _SMSVerificationPageState extends State<SMSVerificationPage>
    with CodeAutoFill {
  TextEditingController pinCodeController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController autoFillCodeController = new TextEditingController();

  _resendCode() async {
    _loadingController.startLoading();
    try {
      String _uuid =
          await AuthUserRepository.of(context).resendCode(widget.phoneNumber);
      _loadingController.stopLoading();
      setState(() {
        _codeResent = true;
        _codeExpiresInXMin = 5;
      });
      startTimer();
      print(_uuid);
    } on ResponseException catch (e) {
      print(e.response.statusCode);
      print(e.response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    } finally {
      _loadingController.stopLoading();
    }
  }

  _verifyCode() async {
    _loadingController.startLoading();
    try {
      AuthUser auth = await AuthUserRepository.of(context).verifyUser(
          widget.uuid,
          pinCodeController.text,
          widget.password,
          widget.requestType);
      // store Auth Tokens
      print(auth.toJson());
      // navigate
      _loadingController.stopLoading();
      if (widget.requestType == "reset_password") {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            (route) => false);
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomePage()),
            (route) => false);
      }
    } on ResponseException catch (e) {
      _codeErr = true;
      print(e.response.statusCode);
      print(e.response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      _codeErr = true;
      print(e.toString());
      throw (e);
    } finally {
      _loadingController.stopLoading();
    }
  }

  String appSignature;
  String otpCode;

  bool _codeErr = false;
  bool _codeResent = false;

  Timer _timer;
  int _codeExpiresInXMin = 5;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneMin = const Duration(minutes: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneMin,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_codeExpiresInXMin < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            _codeExpiresInXMin = _codeExpiresInXMin - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void codeUpdated() {
    setState(() {
      otpCode = code;
      pinCodeController.text = code;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    startTimer();
    listenForCode();
    SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature.then((signature) {
      setState(() {
        appSignature = signature;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final _loadingController = LoadingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoadingWidget(
      controller: _loadingController,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 8.0),
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              "assets/images/Logo.png",
                            ),
                            width: 93,
                            height: 110,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                          child: Text(
                            "RENTTO",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(
                                  color: AppColors.genericColor,
                                ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Enter Verifcation code",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "If you're having any issue, contact to RENTTO",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 25),
                          child: PinCodeTextField(
                            controller: pinCodeController,
                            maxLength: 6,
                            pinBoxWidth: 50,
                            pinBoxHeight: 50,
                            pinBoxRadius: 10,
                            pinBoxBorderWidth: 1,
                            autofocus: true,
                            highlight: true,
                            highlightColor: AppColors.genericColor,
                            hasError: _codeErr,
                            errorBorderColor: Colors.red,
                            pinTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.genericColor,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          child: _codeResent
                              ? Text(
                                  'OTP Code has been resent! Please fill in the code in ' +
                                      _codeExpiresInXMin.toString() +
                                      ' minutes.',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: AppColors.genericColor,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )
                              : Text(
                                  'OTP Code has been sent! Please check your message and fill in the code in ' +
                                      _codeExpiresInXMin.toString() +
                                      ' minutes.',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: AppColors.genericColor,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _loadingController.startLoading();
                            });
                            _resendCode();
                          },
                          child: Text("Resend Code",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                  color: AppColors.genericColor,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 120, vertical: 15),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _loadingController.startLoading();
                              });
                              _verifyCode();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "CONTINUE",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: AppDimens.btnTextSize,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: AppColors.primaryColors,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

flutter doctor -v:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-6.0.pre.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.21.0-6.0.pre.3 at /home/veasnawt/Flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision ddb8e6e3bf (24 hours ago), 2020-07-22 20:00:07 -0700
    • Engine revision dcc9a4048d
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-21.0.dev 9dca49e71e)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/veasnawt/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/90/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/88/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/90/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Linux (desktop)              • linux         • linux-x64      • Linux
    • Web Server (web)             • web-server    • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.129

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: rentto_tenant
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_i18n: ^0.18.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: ^4.3.1
  flutter_dotenv: ^2.1.0
  pin_code_text_field: ^1.2.1
  sms_autofill: ^1.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  intro_slider: ^2.3.1
  fluttertoast: ^7.0.1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.10.0
  json_serializable: ^3.3.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - .env
    - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, I've tried searching on the internet and it seems there is no solution related to it. `enter code here`

Comment: missing plugin exception means, after installing a plugin you have to reinstall the app, hot restart and hot reload only works for Dart code, not the plugin code which happens to be in java/kotlin/swift/objective-c, get the idea?, moreover the question already been asked here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MissingPluginException while using plugin for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter)

Comment: @neuromancer I already reinstalled the app, but nothing changed.

Comment: run `flutter clean` the run `flutter run`

Comment: @Yadu I have tried your method to re-debug the app and I got the result like what I want, but I would like to ask.. if user has already install the app and would like to update the app in playstore, are user available to get this feature (read the phone number) ? or should user uninstall the app then re-install again to get this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I know what the problem is.

The package `sms_autofill` itself is not the cause of the problem, the problem is that the package `flutter_facebook_login` was installed and being unused. Remove or use it properly will solve the problem.