# Url Launcher does not work with MissingPluginException Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to launch a url in my flutter application. What i'm trying to do is very simple and it works in all other projects except for this one! The browser should be launched on an inkwell onTap event. I tried the exact same code in other projects and worked. I also tried to create a new flutter project and the code worked.

The app does not crash and i don't get any error but on Debug i get a missing plugin  exception.

I tried flutter clean and flutter run but didn't work! I tried invalidating cache and restart but also didn't work! I tried removing and re installing the plugin but also didn't work!

Here's the code:

```
_launchMapsUrl() async {
  final url = 'https://www.google.com';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    print('Could not launch $url');
  }
}
```

the onTap:

```
    onTap: () {
      _launchMapsUrl();
   },
```

The Compiled and Target SDK versions are 29 and the version of the launcher in my pubspec.yaml is url_launcher: ^5.7.10

For the record the other projects that the code worked in are of the same versions

I think it has something to do with caching issue i'm not really sure, i'm very new to flutter.

Can you please recommend a solution.

Comment: Answer is here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter]