# flutter url_launcher plugin issue for android release variant

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When trying to run a url on browser with url_launcher plugin, I am getting this error on the release build on android. IOS and the android debug variant works fine.

```
 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)
        #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #1      canLaunch (package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart:124)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #2      _HomeWidgetState.launchURL (package:pool_inspection/src/pages/home/home.dart:323)
        <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here's my code

```
DialogButton(
          color: Color(0xFF0B9CDA),
          child: Text(
            "Login Now",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
             launchURL();
           });
          },
        )
```

Method for url launch

```
Future<void> launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://sometesturl.com';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

url_launcher version

```
url_launcher: ^5.7.10
```

Whats the issue I am unable to trace. I have already tried flutter clean,flutter pub get, Invalidate Cache/Restart as suggested by other answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter check out the issue answers here

Comment: thanks for reply I will check it.