# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method sendRequest on channel com.example.package_sample/sendAndroid)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, missingmethodexception

I have created a pub package. Inside that package I have used some native libraries and wrote some native code. The package worked perfectly fine before publishing on pub. After publishing package on pub.dev the package throws error where I called the native library. The package I created is [here.](https://pub.dev/packages/package_sample/example) and I am using the same code as given in example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter

Comment: @AnmolMishra I have tried these solutions but nothing is working for me.

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing re read this maybe you are doing some mistake if your pkg working fine before published