# How to open popup web in device Preview Flutter

Tags: flutter, device

I'm wanting to navigator myapp to popup web with link url, using flutter_web_browser dependencies, but I think because I use DevicePreview() library (a lib build flutter codes in web using javascript, return UI's result is virtual Iphone, link here: [https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview])
Although i get pub dependencies and flutter run many times, but output is MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openWebPage on channel flutter_web_browser).

I very hope to find solutions for this, because my laptop is poor to run virtual machine from Android studio. Many thanks :((

Comment: Popup web? I think theres no problem showing popup with device preview.

Comment: Check this maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter.

Comment: my project test is the same with this, device preview lib is also a web emulator. Popups in this don't work. Please check to help me 
[https://flutlab.io/editor/1ba2b109-7ea5-4966-a4ec-ea75308ae95f]

Comment: shut down project, pub get and rerun in that link solution don't work with me :((